# Large font size can't make the layout liquid

Tags: html, layout, font-size, liquid-layout

At the begin, I doesn't set the `font-size`, insert a long text in `div`,like:

```
<div>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</div>
```

if I narrow the browser,the overflow part would change to the next line;

but if I set the text `font-size` size to large size,like:

```
<div style="font-size:72px;">asdasdasasdasdasd</div>
```

I narrow the browser, the overflow part couldn't change to the next line:

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/dxXBQ/1/)

So why this happened? How can I fixed the problem? I want no matter how big size I set to the `font-size`, the layout would be liquid as normal

Comment: I don't know about your real content, but to your example, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/dxXBQ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your demo, you didn't give the long string any space, so generally browsers would consider it as one "word" and prefer not to split it.

To split your demo into several lines, add spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/dxXBQ/2/

Of course I believe that's not your real content. If your real content do have long words and you still want them to wrap, use `word-wrap` CSS style: http://jsfiddle.net/dxXBQ/4/